# String case conversion with function

Tags: php

I have used a function for formatting in sentence case. My PHP script function is

```
function sentence_case( $string ) {
    $sentences  = preg_split(
        '/([.?!]+)/', 
        $string, 
        -1, 
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    );

    $new_string = '';
    foreach ( $sentences as $key => $sentence ) {
        $new_string .= ( $key & 1 ) == 0 
            ? ucfirst( strtolower( trim( $sentence ) ) ) 
            : $sentence . ' ';
    }
    $new_string = preg_replace( "/\bi\b/", "I", $new_string );
    //$new_string = preg_replace("/\bi\'\b/", "I'", $new_string);
    $new_string = clean_spaces( $new_string );
    $new_string = m_r_e_s( $new_string );
    return trim( $new_string );
}
```

Though its going well and converting whole string in sentence case. But I wish it would skip characters in single quote. Like my string `HeLLO world! HOw aRE You.` is converting to `Hello world! How are you?`, but I want to skip the content in the single quotes. Like I wish to skip words in the single quotes. `'HELLO' World` and convert words in single quotes to uppercase, otherwise string should remain in sentence case.

Comment: Just a heads-up: you're going to run into all sorts of trouble here with proper nouns.

Comment: I don't think he meant that your english was poor, but rather that proper nouns should be capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another simple regex callback to uppercase words in single quotes. (This is what I understood you want to do.)

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/'(\w+)'/e", 'strtoupper("\'$1\'")', $new_string);
```

If you want this to work for more than one word per quote, use `[\w\s]+` in place of `\w+`. However that would make it more likely to fail for phrases like `isn't` within the text.

Comment: Its adding slashed to the string. like `\\\'HELLO\\\' world. How are you all`

Comment: its adding slashes to the output.

Comment: Oh weird. Add `stripslashes(...)` then around the `strtoupper(..)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the compact and working solution for this task:

```
    $s = preg_replace_callback("~([\.!]\s*\w)|'.+?'~", function($args) {
      return strtoupper($args[sizeof($args) - 1]);
    }, ucfirst(strtolower($s)));
```

For following input:

```
    $s = "HeLLO world! HOw aRE You 'HELLo' iS QuOTed and 'AnothEr' is quoted too";
```

It will produce:

```
    Hello world! How are you 'HELLO' is quoted and 'ANOTHER' is quoted too
```

P.S.
If you are using PHP < 5.3 you can move callback into separate function.